# Generic classes with Inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I am having the below method that returns an instance of a Generic Class. This is a simple factory class. I have a Generic class called FileReader which reads pipe-delimited txt file of Chase,Products, customers, suppliers etc and populate the data into respective BusinessObjects. I am trying to achieve is a Generic file reader. All these business objects derive from BusinessBase class.

```
public override FileReaderGeneric<BusinessBase> CreateFileReader(ImportJobConfig jobConfig)
        {
            return new FileReaderGeneric<Chase>(jobConfig);
        }
```

The BusinessBase is not a generic class. The **BusinessBase** only has validation functions. However, the above code is giving me an error
*Cannot implicitly convert type <BusinessLayer.Chase> to <BusinessLayer.BusinessBase>*

*Edited based on the comments
Looks like my understanding on Generics is not correct*

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is now how to use generics - but we do net a minimal reproducible example, as hinted already, to properly help you correct it. Or you could read the docs on generics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes

Comment: I think you might want to learn about [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) and make your `FileReaderGeneric` type parameter covariant. THis has other implications.

Comment: Without more of your code, all we can do is guess, but you may get a solution if you create a generic class in `T` and constrain `T` to be a `BusinessBase`

Comment: @NineBerry -- I added More details. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C# generics, you cannot cast an instance of a generic class to another. For instance, given

```
class A {
}

class B : A {
}

class Foo<T> where T:A {
}

Foo<A> fooA = new Foo<A>();
Foo<B> fooB = new Foo<B>();
```

Even though A is the supertype of B, you cannot then say

```
fooA = (Foo<A>)fooB;
```

Even though `A` is the supertype of `B`. The language does not allow it: the types `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` are completely unrelated: only their generic parameters are related.

This code:

```
using System;

class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class Foo<T>
    where T : A
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo<A> fooA = new Foo<A>();
        Foo<B> fooB = new Foo<B>();
        Foo<A> xxxx = (Foo<A>)fooB;
    }
}
```

will give you a compilation error `Compilation error (line 22, col 17): Cannot convert type 'Foo<B>' to 'Foo<A>'`

on the assignment statement

```
Foo<A> xxxx = (Foo<A>)fooB;
```

### Updating this to offer possible solutions

Since it sounds like the `BusinessBase` instance that you are instantiating are not exposed to the consumers of the instantiated instances of `FileReaderGeneric<T>`, there are a couple of things you can do.

Assuming that your generic class looks something like this:

```
class FileReaderGeneric<T> where T:BusinessBase
{
  ...
}
```

you can . . .

#### Use Dependency Injection

```
class FileReader
{
  private BusinessBase bb
  private FileReader( BusinessBase bb, ImportJobConfig jobConfig )
  {
    this.bb = bb;
  }

  public static FileReader CreateFileReader( BusinessBase bb , ImportJobConfig jobConfig )
  {
    return new FileReader( bb , jobConfig );
  }

}
```

#### Use An *Abstract Base Class*

```
public abstract class AbstractFileReader
{
  . . .
}

class FileReader<T> : AbstractFileReader where T:BusinessBase
{
  private FileReader( ImportJobConfig jobConfig )
  {
  }

  public static AbstractFileReader CreateFileReader( ImportJobConfig jobConfig )
  {
    return new FileReader<Chase>( jobConfig );
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like my understanding on Generics is not correct. Your example did throw some light into it.

Comment: Note if you use interfaces with covariance, you can do the cast and assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to use a generic method here.  With type constraints, you can limit callers to using a type derived from BusinessBase.  Something like this

```
public override FileReaderGeneric<TBusinessBase> CreateFileReader(ImportJobConfig jobConfig) where TBusinessBase: BusinessBase
{
    return new FileReaderGeneric<TBusinessBase>(jobConfig);
}
```

You will need to change the containing class appropriately because this overriding method no longer has the same signature it did before.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an interface to describe a file reader, and use that interface with a covariant generic type, you can cast the types:

```
public class ImportJobConfig { }

public class BusinessBase { }

public class Chase : BusinessBase { }

public interface IFileReader<in T> { }

public class FileReaderGeneric<T> : IFileReader<T> {
    public FileReaderGeneric(ImportJobConfig jc) { }
}

public override IFileReader<BusinessBase> CreateFileReader(ImportJobConfig jobConfig) {
    return (IFileReader<BusinessBase>)(new FileReaderGeneric<Chase>(jobConfig));
}
```